# How to send an authentication email in django?

Tags: python, django, authentication

How can I use the django email framework that after a user registers, I send him a special link that will confirm his account. I know there are question about how to send emails, but please help me with authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is explained in the post by Farhadur Reja Fahim. TO gain deeper knowledge of the code visit his post [Email COnfirmation](https://medium.com/@frfahim/django-registration-with-confirmation-email-bb5da011e4ef)

settings.py

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'youremail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

token.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import PasswordResetTokenGenerator
from django.utils import six
class TokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
        return (
            six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp) +
            six.text_type(user.is_active)
        )
account_activation_token = TokenGenerator()
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=200, help_text='Required')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from .forms import SignupForm
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.utils.encoding import force_bytes, force_text
from django.utils.http import urlsafe_base64_encode, urlsafe_base64_decode
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from .tokens import account_activation_token
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activate your blog account.'
            message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                        mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()
            return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration')
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form}

def activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_text(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = User.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        # return redirect('home')
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for your email confirmation. Now you can login your account.')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Activation link is invalid!')
```

acc_active_email.html

```
{% autoescape off %}
Hi {{ user.username }},
Please click on the link to confirm your registration,
http://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^signup/$', views.signup, name='signup'),
    url(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        views.activate, name='activate'),
]
```

Comment: django.utils.six is not available anymore

Comment: That's the last thing I want, you've been very helpful. help me find replacement for six.

Comment: @Liel You can use [six](https://pypi.org/project/six/) instead of from django.utils import six.

Comment: [from django.utils import six](https://pypi.org/project/django-utils-six/) Forward compatibility

Answer (score 0):

Forms.py

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False)
        )

    def clean(self):
        user = self.authenticate_via_email()
        if not user:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Sorry, that login was invalid. Please try again.")
        else:
            self.user = user
        return self.cleaned_data

    def authenticate_user(self):
        return authenticate(
            username=self.user.username,
            password=self.cleaned_data['password'])

    def authenticate_via_email(self):
        """
            Authenticate user using email.
            Returns user object if authenticated else None
        """
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if email:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email__iexact=email)
                if user.check_password(self.cleaned_data['password']):
                    return user
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                pass
        return None
```

Views.py

```
def LoginRequest(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)    
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        user = form.authenticate_user()
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('Hello'))

    return render(request, 'login.html',{'form': form})
```

Comment: What about sending the email (I'm not using a username) and is the first code to forms.py?